# MPDF7 not displaying PDF

Tags: mpdf, cakephp-2.5

My MPDF is not properly displaying PDF. I'm currently developing in Cakephp 2.x and I encountered an error on MPDF 7 when I tried to install it. I've already updated my composer dependencies but it still didn't work.

My view/layout:

```
 <?php 
    require_once(APP . 'Vendor' . DS . 'autoload.php');

    $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($this->fetch('content'));
    $mpdf->Output();
 ?>
```

Attached here is the image of the generated error.

[image]
MPDF not displaying PDF

Comment: Looks like you might just need to set the content type to tell the browser that it's PDF data coming?

Comment: It seems that the content type is still HTML.

Comment: The headers are indicating that the content type is HTML?

Comment: https://mpdf.github.io/troubleshooting/strange-character-output-in-browser.html

Comment: Are you really calling the mPDF in your view? The content type is probably overriden some place after. Show more of your code. Try creating the PDF directly in your controller method.

Comment: @GregSchmidt .. it displays HTML content type on headers.

Comment: @Finwe .. I'll try this out. I'm trying to find out what overridden the PDF.

Comment: Yeah, the display is going to be wrong because the content type header is wrong. Might well be wrong because you're doing it in a view instead of the controller; not sure exactly what the method is for returning something as a file in 2.x, but you certainly want to tell Cake that you don't want it rendering any view in this case.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it to render on the controller instead of the view and get back to you ASAP.